# birthday reminder app: function doesn't display

Tags: python

I'm new to programming, and I was trying to build this birthday reminder app without following a specific tutorial, but rather trying to figure it out by myself, but I am stuck.

The first function adds birthdays to .txt file, no problem. But with the second, whether I try to retrieve birthday data from birthday_dict or from the file, the function just doesn't run.

For the second function, I tried to adjust this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/birthday-reminder-application-python/, but it still doesn't work.

If anybody can help me with that, it would be great. Thanks!

```
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta


birthday_dict = {}
def add_to_log():
    name = input("Name: ")
    date_str = input("Birthday (day/month) :")
    birthday_dict.update({name: date_str})
    with open('./venv/birthday_log.txt', mode='a') as birthday_log:
        file = birthday_log.write(f'\n {name}:{date_str}')
    print ('Birthday added!')

def reminder():
    file = open('birthday_log.txt', 'r')
    today = date.today()
    today.strftime("%d/%m")
    flag = 0
    for line in file:
        if today in file:
            line = line.split(':')
            flag = 1
            print (f'Today is {line[1]}\'s birthday!')
```

Comment: You probably wanted to write `if today in line:`, and not `if today in file:`.

Comment: `today.strftime("%d/%m")` will not change the value of `today` - it computes a formatted date string which you then discard. Try `today = date.today().strftime("%d/%m")`

Comment: By the way, I don't know what you intend to use `flag` for, but you might consider using a boolean (`False` or `True`) rather than 0 or 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script contains a couple of mistakes. I will try to address them
one-by-one. I numbered them for reference.

- [1] You don't use the same filename on both functions. In one place you use
  `./venv/birthday_log.txt', and in another place you use` birthday_log.txt`
  (without the subfolder).

  This can be solved by moving the filename into either a global variable or a
  function argument. Especially when you begin programming I highly discourage
  using global variables, so lets use a function argument (see below)
- [2] When using `date.today()` you get today's date as a variable of type
  "date". But when you want to compare that with text, you need to convert it
  to "str". You are doing that correctly by calling `.strftime(...)` on it. But
  that call will *return* the string-value. It will *not* modify the existing
  date object. So you need to store the result in a new variable so you can use
  it later.
- [3] When testing if today's date is found, you are using the `in` operator
  with a date-object (as mentioned in [2]) and a file object which will not
  work. We need to use "strings" on both sides of the `in` operator. On the
  left side we can use the new variable we created in [2] and on the right
  side, we can use `line` which represents the current line we are looping
  over.

### A few more tips:

- You can use `print(type(variable))` to see the type of a variable
- Instead of using `birthday_dict.update({name: date_str})` you can also simply
  write `birthday_dict[name] = date_str`

### Little "exercises"

- Take the two lines I wrote at the very end of the script and move
  them into on "main" function. That way you could use one single variable for
  the filename and remove the duplication of the value. You could use a global
  variable as well, but as mentioned before it is best avoided. Wrapping the
  lines in a "main" function will resolve that issue.
- On global variables: You have one global variables `birthday_dict`. Think
  about how you could make that a "local" variable. Tip: It is very similar to
  the changes made to the filenames.

```
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta


birthday_dict = {}
def add_to_log(filename):
    name = input("Name: ")
    date_str = input("Birthday (day/month) :")
    birthday_dict.update({name: date_str})

    # [1] Using a variable here makes it easier to ensure we only specify the
    # filename once
    with open(filename, mode='a') as birthday_log:
        file = birthday_log.write(f'\n {name}:{date_str}')
    print ('Birthday added!')

def reminder(filename):
    # [1] Using a variable here makes it easier to ensure we only specify the
    # filename once
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    today = date.today()
    # [2] After creating a reference for "today", you need to store the
    # "string" conversion in a new variable and use that later
    today_str = today.strftime("%d/%m")
    flag = 0
    for line in file:
        # [3] You want to check that the date you need is contained in the
        # line, not the file object
        if today_str in line:
            line = line.split(':')
            flag = 1
            print (f'Today is {line[1]}\'s birthday!')


add_to_log("birthday_log.txt")
reminder("birthday_log.txt")
```

Comment: Oh my god!!! it worked!! thank you so much for such a thorough explanation, it makes perfect sense!
 it's my first independent(ish - since I did ask here and you helped) program and I cannot tell you how excited I am right now. Thank you!!

I want to add a couple of other functions here, but I got stuck with the basic mechanism here. I think it will be easy now!

Comment: I recently started streaming on https://twitch.tv/exhuma (every Sunday morning) while I fool around on hobby projects. As you may see in last week's stream, I will *always* take the time to answer and explain beginner questions. Feel free to drop by if you need more guidance.

Answer (score 2):

For viewing all the lines in a file you need to run `.readlines()` from the variable with `open()` and that will make a list as so:

```
file = open("test.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines() # lines = ['hello','test']
```

The `lines` variable will be a list and you can do stuff like this:

```
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Also, you probably want to write `for today in line`, in your second function.

Comment: Now the function is working! Not exactly the way I thought it would, but now I can try to do something from here. Thanks!!